# cypher create relation slow in an OGM embedded Java App

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-ogm

I am testing the performance of the following cypher statement against a database with about 40,000 nodes (importing csv/nodes is fast). I am basically trying to relate children to a parent in a 3 dimensional matrix.

So p is parent, c is child. Row dim is 1, col is dim 2 and level is dim 3

```
match (p:_Cell),(c:_Cell) where p.col = c.col and p.level = c.level and p.row = 'AB' and c.row in ['ABB','ABC','ABD'] create (c)-[:ROW]->(p)
```

I thought that the IN was causing the statement to be slow so changed it an equality which is also very slow. The server executes the statement in 700ms:

```
match (p:_Cell),(c:_Cell) where p.col = c.col and p.level = c.level and p.row = 'AB' and c.row = 'ABB' create (c)-[:ROW]->(p)
```

The server via `localhost:7474` runs very fast less than a second. In the embedded java version it runs over 2 minutes.

I have tried a standard configuration. I also tried setting

```
config.driverConfiguration()                .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver");
        config.set("node_auto_indexing", true);
        config.set("node_keys_indexable","row,col,level");
        config.set("bms.memory.pagecache.size","10g");
        return config;
```

> > Log
> >         09:20:54.571 [main] INFO org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest - Request: match (p:_Cell),(c:_Cell) where p.col = c.col and p.level = c.level and p.row = 'AB' and c.row in ['ABB','ABC','ABD'] create (c)-[:ROW]->(p) with params {}
> >         09:20:54.571 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver - No current transaction, starting a new one
> >         09:20:54.571 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver - Native transaction: org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction
> >         09:22:13.155 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.response.EmbeddedResponse - Response opened: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.response.RestModelResponse
> >         09:22:13.155 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.response.EmbeddedResponse - Response closed: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.response.RestModelResponse
> >         09:22:13.156 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.transaction.EmbeddedTransaction - Committing native transaction: org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction
> >         09:22:13.238 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction - Thread 1: Commit transaction extent: 0
> >     09:22:13.238 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction - Thread 1: Committed
> >         09:22:13.238 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction - Thread 1: Close transaction extent: 0
> >         09:22:13.238 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.Transaction - Thread 1: Closing transaction
> >
> > Neo4j version

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I figured out why the equality version of the cypher statement slow. I was not explicitly managing the transaction. When I added the transaction management the statement is very fast. Oddly, the IN statement is still slow. I am not sure why.

Comment: Is there still a difference in time between embedded and http drivers?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It is a difference between the embedded database and accessing a server instance via the neo4j browser.  The statements take significantly longer to run in the embedded version. I tried the bolt driver and it ran similar to the browser, so I do not think that it is a driver issue.